# How to launch a Metasploit module with arguments in just one command

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I am developing my first *Metasploit* module on *Metasploit v5.0.1*. I would like to launch my own module in one command with args and not using *meterpreter*. At this time, I launch my module with these commands:

```
./msf
use evasion/windows/MyModule
set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_https
set lhost 127.0.0.1
run
```

I would like to run it like

```
./msf --module evasion/windows/MyModule --payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_https --lhost 127.0.0.1
```

It will be more practical to test it like that during my development. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried the -x switch? Could you do it like this `msfconsole -q -x ‘use evasion/windows/MyModule;set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_https;set lhost 127.0.0.1;run’`

Comment: Ok. Run `service postgresql start` first. Then run the command. That should get the database working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Noob123](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/124374/noob123) for the solution. Just enter in the terminal :

```
./msfconsole -q -x 'use evasion/windows/MyModule;set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_https;set lhost 127.0.0.1;run'
```

According to the documentation `./msfconsole --help` :

```
-q, --quiet                      Do not print the banner on startup
-x, --execute-command COMMAND    Execute the specified console commands (use ; for multiples)
```